# Drag Gestures - fractional delta values

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, touch, gestures

I have an issue with objects moving roughly twice as far as expected when dragging them.

I am comparing my application to the standard TouchGestureSample sample from MSDN.

For some reason in my application gesture samples have fractional positions and deltas.

Both are using same Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll, v4.0.30319.

I am running both apps using standard Windows Phone Emulator.

I am setting my break point immediately after this line of code in a simple Update method:

```
GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
```

Typical values in my app:

```
Delta = {X:-13.56522 Y:4.166667}
Position = {X:184.6956 Y:417.7083}
```

Typical values in sample app:

```
Delta = {X:7 Y:16}
Position = {X:497 Y:244}
```

Have anyone seen this issue? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you changed in the code? If the fractional values bother you, you can convert them to some integer type.

Comment: The relevant code is pretty much similar. Thanks, but I prefer to fix causes not consequences.

Comment: Okay, I wouldn't bother with the float / int conversion either. What could be important though, is the difference between "pretty much similar" and "the same".
Is it possible, that the emulator has different settings?

Comment: You don't zoom the screen or something (in the emulator) ?

Comment: @Marton: I will have a closer look.

Comment: @Valmond: I will check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fractional values were caused by IsFullScreen set to false:

```
_graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this)
                {
                    IsFullScreen = false, // Setting to true will make gesture deltas integer.
                    PreferredBackBufferWidth = 480,
                    PreferredBackBufferHeight = 800
                };
```

There is no visual difference between using fractional and integer values.

The bug with multiplied movement was caused by incorrect calculations inside my engine.